# Sql case stetement to check existing records and taking one

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, case

I have two parameters X and Y

Rules for these are *only one* of them can be null. They both can be existing, it's ok but they both can't be null.

I'm using this to check if they exist in database so I can assign one and rest of the SP can continue inserting.

```
SELECT @Id=id FROM Table WHERE (No = @x) OR (No = @y)
```

What I want to add is if they are both existing I want the Id to be the Id of @x.

I can't get the Case Statement right in my mind. Normally this is a no brainer but somehow I managed to get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISNULL() will take the first non null value it finds.

```
SELECT @Id=id FROM Table WHERE No = ISNULL(@x, @y)
```